# How to get a flat list of data to be groups of items with sub-headers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with of data similar to what I have in the picture below.  That is, complete records all in each row.

I want to create a way to view the data sorted and grouped by the particular column.  That is, in this data, I want to be able to view: All the painters grouped by Age; All the people grouped by office;  People by Job Type, etc.

I want to easily switch back and forth between the different views. I've tried pivot tables but that seems to be good for totally colummns but have not figured out how to do the groupings.

[image]

Comment: I would still use pivot tables. Try experimenting with putting all properties as ROWS then expand all in the pivot dataset and change the order in the ROWS section to help filter the data. Switch off sub totaling and consider adding a single dummy column of ones for VALUEs in the pivot table if necessary.

Comment: In my opinion, you can try to use Slicer with Pivot Table to help you: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-slicers-to-filter-data-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d